# Answer with biblical documentation deleted

Tags: support, answers

I posted an answer here to [Should I charge my children interest when they borrow money?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63802/should-i-charge-my-children-interest-when-they-borrow-money/63817#63817)

The answer was live for a couple days but I see that a moderator has deleted it. I am confident that I appropriately answered the question, and so if possible, I would like for this answer to be undeleted.

Below is my deleted answer to [Should I charge...money?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63802/should-i-charge-my-children-interest-when-they-borrow-money/63817#63817)

---

Ultimately for me, the answer to this question is pretty much a "no", but keep reading anyways. The following are passages from the Bible (nasb version).

here is an excerpt from Deuteronomy 23:

> You shall not charge interest to your countrymen: interest on money,
>   food, or anything that may be loaned at interest. You may charge
>   interest to a foreigner, but to your countrymen you shall not charge
>   interest, so that the LORD your God may bless you in all that you
>   undertake in the land which you are about to enter to possess.

From Exodus 22, it specifies "to the poor among you":

> If you lend money to My people, to the poor among you, you are not to
>   act as a creditor to him; you shall not charge him interest.

There are also many quotes from the New Testament that encourage more kinds of "selfless" giving. For example, from Matthew:

> Give to him who asks of you, and do not turn away from him who wants
>   to borrow from you.

Based on these passages I would suggest that you try to inform your kids about the rules of your loans. If they aren't paying them back because they have a habit of mismanaging their money, or are lazy, then perhaps you don't offer them any more money until they pay their first debt back.

But if their neediness isn't necessarily their fault, or they sincerely apologize, then perhaps you give them a loan.

Yet in either of these circumstances, it doesn't really make sense to charge interest on a new loan. In the first example, if you can't get your previous debt paid for, then just "charging interest" doesn't seem to help the situation.

But if there's anything to garner from this discussion, it's that generosity (and forgiveness) are important.

Comment: Serious question: Would you have preferred it be edited to remove the biblical references, which didn't really add weight to your argument and which tend to attract nonproductive and off topic argument?

Comment: @keshlam Thank you for the question. My answer would then be: Was my answer harmful? The biblical content is my source, which shouldn't be removed, and which distinguishes my answer from one that is purely opinionated.

Comment: It was almost guaranteed to drag us into a discussion of religion. Since that is off topic here and unrelated to the question at hand ( except as the source of your own moral sense), that could indeed be considered harmful. This is a case, I think, of picking where and when. Remember, non-believers don't consider interpretation of the Bible to be significantly more than opinion, especially as interpretations disagree.

Comment: @keshlam Answers of Christianity don't always cause long discussions of disagreement. My answer was live for about two days, and only had three comments total. I was not stirring up a crowd.

Comment: Not that I was accused of causing disruption...but what I mean is that I just don't think that there was anything wrong with what I posted. I understand that it is controversial, but does that mean it should be deleted? I think my answer should've been left alone, if people don't like it it will get downvoted anyway...

Comment: @bmende you claimed that the other answer is "purely opinionated", yet your own answer is purely your own opinion. The book you quoted is not an authority to anything and most people would consider your trying to force them follow it an act of oppression and aggression. I certainly do and anyone arguing with me trying to base their argument on the Koran (or whatever other "holy" book you chose to quote, they're all the same) lost the argument by default.

Comment: @littleadv I'm not trying to "force" anyone to follow anything. I believe that the Bible is God-inspired, and so is useful in all areas of life.

Comment: @bmende so, your answer is just as purely opinionated as the other one, except that you found it necessary to show off your religion. Why? If the religious claims are not part of the answer - then just state your opinion. If you're here to force your beliefs in imaginary friends on others - then you're not welcome.

Comment: @littleadv when I spoke about opinion, I wasn't referring to any particular answer from the question. The religion is a part of my answer.

Comment: And also to explain, I don't think that answers primarily based off opinion are necessarily wrong, but what I mean is that generally speaking,  answers with sources are more SE oriented than those without.

Comment: @bmende I think you're missing my point. Your religion = your opinion. If you claim opinionated answers shouldn't be here (which is correct) - then you should also keep your religion to yourself. I personally am deeply offended by people trying to push their beliefs down my throat. I don't care what books you read in your bedroom, just keep it to yourself. Don't go around parading your crosses, guns, or whatever else method of murder you worship.

Comment: It would be possible to say your answer was guided by your faith without quoting chapter and verse at us, and the result would have been less likely to cause discomfort for those who don't share your faith. As I said, for non believers that book carries history but no authority, and may actually weaken your argument... And believers don't need the quotes.

Comment: (Seriously, the quotes come across as if you are lecturing/preaching at us, and that isn't what any of us are here for.)

Comment: @keshlam You are right in that I could have posted my answer without the references, but then how would that benefit non believers, or believers alike? For someone like me, if I saw an answer like mine without biblical links, I wouldn't pay as much attention. I'm always concerned with following someone's moral advice, without having some biblical basis for it. There is just too much conflicting advice out there, and wrong advice, that "sounds" good. But I understand there will be a lot of opposition to my answer.

Comment: @bmende, if that's your standard for acceptable advice, you are going to be very uncomfortable here. Up to you whether to follow these suggestions or not, but don't be surprised if not doing so results in your continuing to have your words ignored, removed, or both. You've heard the concerns; what you do with them is now in your hands. Choose wisely.

Comment: There are times and places for biblical references. This is neither.

Comment: I was raised by Jesuits, these guys were keepers of knowledge during the dark ages.  They taught me that the Bible is not a history book and that science and religion can coexist.  

Now it seems we have regressed where people think its not only a history book but a science book and now today also an economics book.  So for Christians who think the Bible is allegorical its frustrating.

Why arn't Christians up in arms about aren't the modern day moneylenders who trashed the world economy.

Comment: @MarkMonforti Indeed, there are many different beliefs and denominations out there with conflicting advice on how literal or figurative the Bible is. That's why it's just so important for people to find a good translation and read themselves so that they can draw the right conclusions. About the world economy, I suppose that many people don't really understand it (eh, pretty complicated, no?), or are content with the way things are.

Answer (score 6):

I can appreciate your religion.  I can appreciate that you live your life as best you can while following your religion as best you can.  I can appreciate that you wanted to share that with the people here.  I find your response here to be largely benign, though definitely off topic.

Typically when a source is posted here, it's to cite a specific piece of tax code or some other legal document or code section, not to support an opinion.  That particular question was already a poor fit for this site.  An argument was brewing in the comments section and there were several, largely useless, answers.

"Should I loan money to my kid," who cares; do what you want.

"What is the tax impact of loaning money to my kid," this is relevant to the site.

I can appreciate your attempt, though futile, to lend some "authority" to your opinion, but the question is a waste of time and religion isn't an authority here.  I don't necessarily agree with deleting your single response because I don't see it as any better or worse than any of the other responses; but I would fully support deleting that entire question.

Comment: "Should I loan money to my kid," VTC: POB

Answer (score 5):

Reading through the comments, you're fighting a losing battle, here.

There are certainly SE communities where religious discussion is encouraged (see [Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/)), but it's not a great fit for Money.SE. Even the question to which you responded has been [closed as off-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/63802/should-i-charge-my-children-interest-when-they-borrow-money/63817#63817), since it's asking for opinions and personal beliefs.

While your answer may have been a relatively good fit for the question as it was framed, the question itself wasn't a good fit for the site.

To follow up on what keshlam said: There is very little (or nothing) in the way of biblical references for the advice and answers on here. Given the nature of the questions posted here, most of the references and rooted in maths or established laws, regulations, guidelines, and operating rules.